# Mongoose UpdateMany not updating

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions

In my application Items can have subitems, children.
Those children have a parentId to reference their parent Item.

With the function posted below I want to move the children of an Item to the same hierarchy level by giving them the same parentId as their parent, turning them to what are basically siblings.

When I try doing that with the code posted below, using the updateMany method, nothing happens. Nothing changes. At all. BUT: the console log of "update" shows

```
update {
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

indicating that one child in my example is modified. But again, nothing happened.

Above the use of the updateMany method I have a code section that is commented out. In this section I tried updating every child individually using the save method. This bit works perfectly and gets me to the desired result. This gives me the confidence that there are no larger issues with my approach in general but that I am apparantly doing something wrong with updateMany.

While I could leave it at that, I still can´t wrap my head around what is wrong here and can´t go to sleep until I know :D

Thanks in advance!

Additional info:
I am using sessions/transactions because I want to add more complex functionality to the function later on. Transactions will be required. Also, I am running this as a NEXT.js server action. My database is running on MongoDB Atlas.

```
export const moveChildren = async ({ id }) => {
    await dbConnect();
    const session = await startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
        const item = await Item.findById(id).session(session);
        console.log(id, item.parentId);

        const children = await Item.find({parentId: id}).session(session);
        console.log("children", children);

        // for (let index = 0; index < children.length; index++) {
        //     const child = children[index];
        //     child.parentId = item.parentId;
        //     await child.save({ session });
        //     console.log(child);
        // }

        const update = await Item.updateMany({parentId: id}, {parentId: item.parentId}).session(session);
        console.log("update", update);

        await session.commitTransaction();
        return success({});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await session.abortTransaction();
        return failure({ error });
    } finally {
        await session.endSession();
    }
};
```

Like described above, I already tried updating each child individually (in the out-commented code section) and this gets the desired result of updating their parentId to the same id as their original parent.

Comment: You might try opening a changestream on that collection to watch what changes actually happen, and/or enabling auditing/profiling so you can see the exact query that reached the server.

Comment: Thanks Joe, good idea.
I enabled loggin for mongoose and this is what the updateMany executing shows:

Mongoose: Items.updateMany({ parentId: ObjectId("65e9de0a4888f8f860b33a01") }, { '$setOnInsert': { createdAt: new Date("Sat, 09 Mar 2024 09:51:52 GMT") }, '$set': { updatedAt: new Date("Sat, 09 Mar 2024 09:51:52 GMT") }}, { session: ClientSession("c59b483254e346f088bb5ae406108397") })

It seems like the parentId field is not even relevant in the execution. What could be wrong?

Comment: In the schema is parentId a ref?

Comment: Yes, it is! "parentId: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: "Item" }"

Comment: You might try disabling [strict](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) in the schema, or query directly with the underlying node.js client